# Gradle: how to exclude jar from an ear file?

Tags: gradle, jar, dependencies, war, ear

I have a question regarding excluding a jar file from an ear artifact. My project has the following modules:

```
project
 - ejb_module
 - war_module
 - ear_module
 - other_module
```

In my `ear_module/build.gradle` :

```
dependencies {
    deploy project(ejb_module)
    earlib project(ejb_module)

    deploy project(war_module)
    earlib project(war_module)
}
```

The problem is how I exclude the jar artifact produced from the `war_module`.

The `war_module` produces both war and jar artifact. The reason I need the jar artifact is that my `other_module` depends on it.

A complicated factor is that the `war_module` has some dependencies that needs to go via `earlib`.

So my question is how I exclude the `war_module.jar` from the ear file? It is included both at root and in `APP-INF/lib`.

Answer (score 0):

I presume in your `war_module` you are applying both `war` and `java` plugins to get a `.war.` and `.jar` artifacts ?

Try:

```
deploy project(path: 'war_module', configuration: 'archives')
earlib project(path: 'war_module', configuration: 'archives')
```

It should pick up a `.war` only because if look into the Gradle war plugin code you can see that it overrides the default output of the project, if java plugin was included.

Additionally, war plugin uses java plugin to compile your code under the hood.

---

You, of course, can simply **exclude the artefact from the build** by using

```
config (project){exclude module: 'name'}
```

but I think this is not the best you can do here.

---

Try looking into `providedRuntime` and `runtimeOnly` configurations depending on which version of Gradle do you use.

If the artefact is used for compilation then `compileOnly` etc.

This configuration used in `dependecies{}` will use the jar but will not be going to expose it anywhere else then it should not land in any artefact that you build and this is probably what would fit you the most in your case, but the question wasn't asking about this it's just an advice.

Comment: Thanks but it did not work. I came closer by adding:
    foo {
        extendsFrom runtime
    }

but it still includes the jar file from the war_module. configuration: archives did not have effect.

Comment: Then something is messed up in your architecture I think. How do you create a war and a jar?

Answer (score 0):

Assume your EAR contains an another existing jar, said `xxx.yyy.zzz.jar`.

In your ear project's `build.gradle`, add the following

```
ext.replacement = 'your.group:xxx.yyy.zzz:your.version'

configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
            // remove to.be.excluded.jar
            if (details.requested.group == 'your.group' &&
                details.requested.name == 'to.be.excluded' && 
                details.requested.version == 'your.version') {
                details.useTarget replacement
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This way, the `to.be.excluded.jar` will be replaced by `xxx.yyy.zzz.jar`, that virtually removes it from the EAR.